# Javascript mouse wheel event stop

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to stop the mouse wheel event to stop triggering after after call ? I am trying to switch between pages (one page at a time/ like one page per scroll but the scroll should happen at top 500ms) using this logic but the event keeps calling my method even if I remove the listener:

```
const listenToWheel = (event) => {
    console.log("SCROLL");
    removeScrollEventListener();
    console.log("DO STUFF");
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
      getPreviousPage();
    } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      getNextPage();
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      addScrollEventListener();
    }, 800);
  };


const addScrollEventListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", listenToWheel);
  };

  const removeScrollEventListener = () => {
    window.removeEventListener("wheel", listenToWheel);
  };
```

Comment: add a boolean `if (fetching) return` set it to true when loading and when you are done loading, set it to false

Comment: @epascarello Just by adding that doesn't work. The loading is done in 10ms so in that period the wheel listener is still running and will call getNextPage() about 10 times. I have added a timeout but its not the exact behaviour i want. I want to stop listening to scroll and then re enable it somehow.

Comment: Unclear how it would not work. You set the Boolean back to true when you want it enabled. So if it is too quick means you are setting it back too soon. Using `debounce` for the scroll event would also help

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your last 2 blocks like this:

```
const addScrollEventListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", listenToWheel);
  };

  const removeScrollEventListener = () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousewheel", listenToWheel);
  };
```

as some browsers prefer mousewheel event over wheel.

Comment: This is not changing anything